# may/might .... but

Tags: grammar

My grammar book says that this structure : may/might...but is used to say that something is true but that makes no difference to the main argument.

Some examples from the book:

(1) He **may** be clever, but he hasn't got much common sense.

(2) It **may** be a comfortable car, but it uses a lot of fuel.

I wonder if I can use "might" instead of "may" in (1) and (2):

(3) He **might** be clever, but he hasn't got much common sense.

(4) It **might** be a comfortable car, but it uses a lot of fuel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, "might" is interchangeable with "may" in those sentences. Some people consider "might" to convey even less certainty than "may", but the difference is pretty minor.

Keep in mind that "may/might . . . but" could also be used for other meanings (besides what that grammar book says). For example:

> I might go out tonight, but on the other hand I might stay home.

Comment: I might go out tonight, but on the other hand I might stay home.
=> "might" here show possibility. Right?

Comment: @LEHANH Yes, just as it does in your examples. However, in my example the first half of the sentence is just as important for the main argument as the second half.